# Glassfish 2.1 never reuses statements with Postgresql and Eclipselink?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipselink

We are using Glassfish server 2.1 with Eclipselink JPA 2.1 and connect to a PostgreSQL database 8.4.8.
The problem is that in the log file of Postgres I always see a prepare of the statements that were created with em.createQuery or em.createNamedQuery.
It seems that no statement that has been prepared is reused. Therefore the performance is really bad.

I tried setting the default JDBC setting prepareThreshold from 5 to 1. 
That only changed that the unnamed statements were now named. But they were still not reused.

I also tried several settings for the connection pooling as prepared statements are connection dependent but returned to the default org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource and javax.sql.DataSouce.

I enabled statement caching also in the persistence.xml:

`<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true"/>`

Does Glassfish 2.1 support statement caching? And if it does what are the settings I missed?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: So apparantly we will have to update to Glassfish 3.

Comment: I've had some fun with doing that.  I'm able to get our app working on GF 3.1, and now working on getting a full cluster set up to replace our GF 2.1 stand-alone instances as well as a cluster.  I often wish I was using Postgres like you.  I've really come to dislike MySQL which I'm stuck with now.  Having used Postgres before, it was so much nicer in so many way. 

Anyway, I'm really liking GF 3.1 over 2.1.  No more node-agents, so less memory usage.  It's been easier to manage the cluster, easier to install, and somewhat faster than 2.1. Upgrading from JEE 5 to 6 was somewhat painful though.

Comment: I know what you are talking about. We are still having a hard time upgrading to GF 3.1 and therefore JEE6. Probably a reason for some new questions here on SO. Thank you for your quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfx_M0p0KoM it seems that 2.1 does not support statement caching.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

Here is the link to the statement caching setting in GlassFish 3.1:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/giyck.html#giyci

Here is a developer blog entry explaining the new feature in detail:
http://blogs.oracle.com/technical/entry/statement_caching_in_glassfish_v3